# Linux change directory from an executable bash file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file in `/usr/bin` called `code`, which contains the following:

```
cd ~/Documents/Code
```

However, when I run it by simply executing

```
$ code
```

Nothing happens.  Why is this, and how can I make `code` perform as I would like?

Comment: If that file is in /usr/bin because it's on the PATH and executable,  you can run it in your current shell with `. $(which code)`, but there are better ways to cd, one is mentioned by Jonathon.

Comment: @Vytenis I think you should add this as an alternative answer. Being able to run a script *in the current shell* is another valid way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `code`, a *new* process is spawned to execute that script. The script changes directories (*for his process*) and returns. Your original shell's process still has the same working directory. Child processes cannot manipulate the state of their parent.

A better way to accomplish this would be with an [`alias`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html). Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias code='cd ~/Documents/Code'
```

Answer (score 1):

If that file is in /usr/bin because it's on the PATH and executable, you can run it in your current shell with `. $(which code)` or `source $(which code)`, but there are better ways to cd, one is mentioned by Jonathon.